# AngularJS Download Settings from Servers

Tags: angularjs, configuration, application-settings

We have an endpoint on our API that includes a set of settings (like default text, other endpoints, etc.). Our frontend is written in AngularJS and we're trying to figure out the best way to get them back to the client, and make them available throughout all directives in the application. Right now our best solution is to include `settings` as a directive:

```
angular.module('ourapp')
    .factory('settings', function ($http) {
        var url = 'http://localhost:8080/settings';
        return function (callback){
            $http.get(url).success(callback);
        };
    });
```

But then all the other calls are wrapped asynchronously.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: We ended up doing a synchronous XHTTP call outside of angular and binding the results to the angular global settings object.

Answer (score 0):

Since the settings come asynchronously from the server, their availability will inherently be asynchronous. If your logic depends on the settings being available, then there is probably no better solution than using promises.

```
angular.module('ourapp').factory('settings', function($http) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:8080/settings';
    return $http.get(url); // returns a promise
});
```

You could use `$route` to resolve the promise before instantiating controllers. The settings would then be synchronously available in the controllers.

You can also simulate promise unwrapping, i.e. immediately (synchronously) returning an object, which later will be filled with real data. This is great for scopes and templates, and was previously a feature of Angular itself. Be aware that the simulated promise unwrapping may cause bugs if not used cautiously, because the settings data may or may not be there.

Example:

```
angular.module('ourapp').factory('settings', function($http) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:8080/settings';
    var settings = {};
    $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
        angular.extend(settings, data); // fills in data from server
    });
    return settings; // immediately (synchronously) returned
});
```